Display from top to bottom in PlantUML
How can I display these three classes from top to bottom rather than from bottom to top? Thus, C1 (and C1a), then C2, then C3, following the order in the code?
@startuml Example
left to right direction

class "C1" {}
class "C1a" {}

"C1" <|-- "C1a"

class "C2" {}

class "C3" {}

@enduml

The doc suggests that laying out from bottom to top (when using “left to right”) rather than conversely seems to be the intended behavior, but I did not find how to get the reverse behavior (which would seem much more natural to me).
Lots of questions on SO wonder about laying out components in PlantUML but I did not find a question involving the vertical axis direction when using “left to right”.
I realize that I can add hidden arrows between components to position them explicitly, but I am looking for something that does not require to explicitly mention each class. The goal is to make the code more readable and more easily maintainable (by making the diagram closer to what the diagram code expresses).

The GraphViz layouts don't really use the same goal (maintainability) as you describe. They try to make a graph, with a pretty complex strategy. https://crashedmind.github.io/PlantUMLHitchhikersGuide/layout/layout.html

This blog entry has some good pointers -- it's complex: https://www.augmentedmind.de/2021/01/17/plantuml-layout-tutorial-styles/
